# How to tell the query optimizer in SAP Hana to treat union blocks separately?

Tags: sql, hana

I have an SQL statement of the form

```
SELECT some stuff
union all 
SELECT some more stuff
```

The two statements are fairly complicated but if I execute them separately each takes a few seconds, the first has around 100 million rows, the second one only around 12000. If I put the statements together like this, the database works for about 15 minutes and then aborts with the error message 'column search intermediate result exceeds 2 billion rows limitation'.

I assume this happens because the optimizer tries to work on the statement as a whole and aparently makes some bad choices regarding the order of the operations. As it is doing fine on the individual statements it should be sufficient to tell the optimizer to only look at them individually and not try to optimize the entire statement. Is there an easy way to put some 'boxes' around the statements so they are treated individually?

Comment: Run the queries separately?

Comment: @jarlh They sit inside a bigger query that has some group by clauses, so I do want to aggregate the two in my application.

Comment: Is it oracle database or sap hana? One of the tags should be removed

Comment: And are you sure that you **fetch** all 100mln rows in few seconds?

Comment: Looks like you get just first few rows, not all

Comment: „I assume this happens“ - have you looked at the resulting query plans in plan viz to verify that doubt?

Comment: Execution engine is capable to execute `union` in parallel, so you need to check the query plan (especially with PlanViz to see the most resource consuming operator)

Comment: If this is SAP Hana table function or something that supports it, set the 2 up as separate table variables with the WITH HINT(NO_INLINE) on them.
Then union them afterwards - it'll force the compiler to execute them seperately and put the results into memory before unioning.
If the one query is huge, maybe just force the HINT on the smaller one.